# How to convert type_info to a 'Class' type of objective-c

Tags: types, casting, objective-c++, typeinfo

Say I have a C++ class:

```
class CppClass {
    // class implementation.
}
```

And in Objective-C++ code I have a method:

```
+(id)someMethod:(Class)aClass;
```

Is there any way to convert `type_info` to `Class`?

Comment: What is `type_info` you are talking about?

Comment: @trungduc The class returned by the `typeid`

Comment: No, you can't. There is no way to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. `Class` is a type that can be used to hold a pointer to an Objective-C "class object", an Objective-C object that represents an Objective-C class at runtime. C++ classes are not Objective-C classes, and don't have an Objective-C "class object".

Comment: This is true. That said, if the OP's practical problem is how to implement code in C++ when the method expects them to provide an ObjC class, the answer is: wrap the C++ in an ObjC class. I.e. write an ObjC class that creates the C++ object in its `-init` method, `delete`s it in its `-dealloc` method, and forwards any ObjC methods it needs to implement to the C++ class.